# How to trigger click on NStableView binded by NSArrayController

Tags: xcode, macos, swift2, appkit

I am creating today extension for OSX.
An NSArrayController binds to NSSearchField, and search result shows properly on NSTableView.

How can I trigger click event on the search result, and take clicked Item?

I have set tableViewSelectionDidChange function, but it is not called even after my click event.

Comment: Does tableViewSelectionDidChange fire when clicking on a row when you're not searching?

Comment: No, it does not fire on the click both on before and after searching.

Comment: Did you set the NSTableViewDelegate?

Comment: It became to trigger when I add the delegate (to File's Owner) on NSTableView, but items in the table became to be empty. Also it became to be available when I remove the delegate from BI. Am I missing any?

Comment: The blank table resolved by reassigning tablecellview on tableview function. It seems like binding twice from BI and program side, though it is fine anyway. Thanks rocky!